# Subset a dataframe using shiny user authentication method

Tags: r, shiny, shinyauthr

I have the following shiny app below which uses user authentication logic. As you can see first of all a dataframe is created with:

```
# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- data.frame(
  user = c("user1", "user2","user1"),
  password = c("pass1", "pass2","pass1"), 
  permissions = c("admin", "standard","admin"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two","User One"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

From this dataframe the user uses the `user` for username and the `password` for password in order to log in the app. As you will see I can log-in into the app and see the table only with `user2` credentials as `user1` exists in 2 rows of my dataframe. If I skip the 3rd row it works. My goal is to subset the original dataframe `user_base` based on the username and password I will use but now I can see that if I have more than one rows with the same username this does not work. A bonus question is if it possible to skip the password and enable the user to log in using only the username.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)
library(shinyjs)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- data.frame(
  user = c("user1", "user2","user1"),
  password = c("pass1", "pass2","pass1"), 
  permissions = c("admin", "standard","admin"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two","User One"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # must turn shinyjs on
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  # add logout button UI 
  div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
  # add login panel UI function
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
  # setup table output to show user info after login
  tableOutput("user_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # call the logout module with reactive trigger to hide/show
  logout_init <- callModule(shinyauthr::logout, 
                            id = "logout", 
                            active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth))

  # call login module supplying data frame, user and password cols
  # and reactive trigger
  credentials <- callModule(shinyauthr::login, 
                            id = "login", 
                            data = user_base,
                            user_col = user,
                            pwd_col = password,
                            log_out = reactive(logout_init()))

  # pulls out the user information returned from login module
  user_data <- reactive({credentials()$info})

  output$user_table <- renderTable({
    # use req to only render results when credentials()$user_auth is TRUE
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    user_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the shinyauthr package, but if it doesn't like duplicate rows in the user table, try removing them using `unique`?

Comment: I do not want to remove them. I want to use them all like subeseting the dataframe to all the rows that include the "user1".